# variable from one component to another is not working in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I am working in **Angular 9.1.3**.

I have two component `admin` and `header`.
I have to print/pass the variable from admin to header component. But saying the variable is `undefined`.

My admin component: **admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  access_token:any;
  userdata: any;
  userName: any;
  parentMessage:any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getetUser();
    this.parentMessage = "message from Admin";
  }
  }
```

My header component: **header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { AdminComponent } from '../admin/admin.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("parentMessage") modifiedName;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("This is the admin data "+ this.modifiedName); //This is the admin data undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable from parent to child component through HTML.

In the admin.component.html

```
    <app-header [parentMessage]="parentMessage"></app-header>
```

Comment: When I add the above code in `admin.component.html` the contents in that page get replicate twice

Comment: Can you please share your admin.component.htrml file?

Comment: 'admin.component.html' contain some html codes only. A div only.

Comment: Does the div in the admin.component.html contains header code? Because it should not show replicated code if <app-header [parentMessage]="parentMessage"></app-header> is only added once.

Comment: Actually `<app-header></app-header>` is loaded in `app.component.ts`. since the header is need in all pages.

Comment: ok understand why its shows twice. but i put `[parentMessage]="parentMessage"` in `app.component.ts`. but not working shows some error. I think its not available there.

Comment: May I know what is the error? And maybe you can recreate in https://stackblitz.com. So I can check easily. Thanks